# SyntaxError: Unexpected token () in javascript - Closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am new to Javascript, trying to learn the concept of encapsulation - `getter/setter` in Javascript. However, I am running into a compilation/interpreter issue.
I have followed a link but I am unable to figure out what's wrong.

My understanding is correct that this is returning an object from the closure function. This object has got two methods - getter and setter. However, I am getting compilation/interpreter here. What's the problem here? Could you please throw some light on it. I am using webstorm editor.

```js
function testConcept() 
{
  var testID = 1000;

  return 
  {
    getID: function() 
    {
      return testID;
    },

    setID: function(newTestID) 
    {
      testID = newTestID;
    }
  }
}

var test = testConcept();
console.log(test.getID());
test.setID(2009);
console.log(test.getID());
```

Here is the error

```
      getID: function()
                       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Comment: javascript is forgiving with `;` ... but, it doesn't always get it right, especially with return - it assumes a return on a line by itself is meant to be `return;`

Comment: A common coding convention in javascript is to put the opening `{` on the same line as the start of the expression it's part of, so `function() {`,  `return {`, `if (...) {` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Move up the `object's` brace `{` on the line of the `return` statement :

```
 // this is returing an object
return {
```

`Javascript` automatically put an `;` after the `return` statement, so you get the error. After setting comma you get something like `return ;` and then your `object's` body, so here is the error.

```js
function testConcept()
{
    var testID = 1000;
    
    return {
        getID: function()
        {
            return testID;
        },
        setID: function(newTestID)
        {
            testID = newTestID;
        }
    }
}

var test = testConcept();
console.log(test.getID());
test.setID(2009);
console.log(test.getID());
```

Comment: the following "object" is no longer considered to be an `object`

Comment: You are right, I said object for the OP what to consider

Comment: have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unnamed_function_statement

Comment: so, is it a rule that never do an enter after return or put comments.  in fact, put a curly brace immediately on the same line.

Comment: I only pointed it out because if the return value was something very simple like `{
        hello: 'world'
    }` - i.e. an object with a single non function property, the code would `parse` and some browsers would issue a warning about unreachable code after return, but there would be no error in the console as such